# Why 32-bit installation of R is available in 64-bit machines?

Tags: installation, 32-bit, installer, r, 32-vs-64-bit

I wanted to know why, when you install R for Windows on a x64 machine, it lets you choose between installing 64-bit,32-bit, or both.

I don't understand why would you want to install 32-bit version of R. Maybe it's for backwards compatibility, I'm curious.

Thank you!

Comment: Say you have a huge collection of 32-bit R package binaries, or even package source code that hasn't yet been ported to 64-bits.

Comment: [Some basic answers here](http://www.altova.com/64-bit.html) Some reasons are dependent on what specific software that is to be installed.

Comment: [More answers here](http://www.howtogeek.com/194119/why-are-most-programs-still-32-bit-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows/)